# Google App Engine - Error 503_Service Unavailable

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am coding a simple gae webapp that should send me an email from a form:

I have coded that gae code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>A form</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="/feedback" method="post">

  <!-- Simple text field -->
 <label for="name">Name </label>
 <input type="text" name="name"/>
 <br/>

  <!-- Email -->
 <label for="email">Email </label>
 <input type="email" name="email"/>
 <br/>


  <!-- Textarea -->
 <label for="description">Description </label>
 <textarea  name="description" cols="50" rows="5">Type your comment here</textarea>
 <br/>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request" action="/feedback"/>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FeedbackServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>at.wunderapps.servlets.FeedbackServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FeedbackServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/feedback</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FeedbackServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String description = req.getParameter("description");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        String msgBody = name  + description + email + " :EMAIL";

        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("apps@gmail.com",
                    "Es FUNKTIONIERT!!!"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("my.mail@mail.com", "Your name"));
            msg.setSubject("Bestellung");
            msg.setText(msgBody);
            Transport.send(msg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println(
                "Thanks you for your feedback. An Email has been send out.");
    }
}
```

When I am doing localhost i get:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

and the exceptions I get are:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at.wunderapps.servlets
>
> CRITICAL: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException: at.wunderapps.servlets
>
> 20.07.2012 13:13:46 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn WARNUNG: failed FeedbackServlet: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   20.07.2012 13:13:46 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn WARNUNG: Failed startup of context
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@495c998a{/,C:\Users\Desktop\mailservice\war}
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I guess the problem could be that the inde.html does not find my servlet. But why, cause the web.xml seems to be alright? Can you please help me?

PS.: I am running it on windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<servlet-class>at.wunderapps.servlets.FeedbackServlet</servlet-class>
```

If that is the fully qualified name of your servlet, then the first line of the  FeedbackServlet.java  file should be

```
package at.wunderapps.servlets;
```

and the FeedbackServlet.class file should be at

```
<yourWebAppRootFolder>/WEB-INF/classes/at/wunderapps/servlets/FeedbackServlet.class
```

Or if you are using Eclipse for your IDE, then just place your code in

```
<yourWebAppRootFolder>/src/at/wunderapps/servlets/FeedbackServlet.java
```